# Can't setup GtkX11Display xevent signal

Tags: x11, gtk3

I'm trying to set up the "xevent" signal documented here:

https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gdk/x11/gdkdisplay-x11.c

in the gdk_x11_display_class_init function.

Here's my code:

```
static gboolean TheCallback(GdkDisplay * display,
                            XEvent * xevent,
                            gpointer user_data)
{
   std::cout << "yo" << std::endl;

   return FALSE;
}

int main(void)
{
   gtk_init(NULL,NULL);

   GtkWidget * win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

   gtk_widget_show_all(win);

   GdkDisplay* gd = gdk_display_get_default();

   g_signal_connect(gd,"xevent",G_CALLBACK(TheCallback),NULL);

   gtk_main();
}
```

But i just get:

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2523: signal 'xevent' is invalid for instance '0xd890e0' of type 'GdkX11Display'

What am i missing?